# Stretchable and Pattern UIImage at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, orientation

I would like to code a shelf and I don't want to think about resizing and changing background images on a rotation and depending on the screensize (iPad/iPhone). Is it possible to create an image, that would stretch horizontally but repeat vertically?
By now, I've only found the `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` and `[UIImage strechableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]` or the new `[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]`. But I didn't manage to let them work together, obviously.

I hope the illustration helps understanding my issue:

[image: Illustration]

Do you have any idea how to accomplish the above, so that it will work with a single image for different sizes and orientations? Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what sort of result do you get for `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage resizableImage...]]`?

Comment: The image is not streched or resized, just repeated over x and y.

Comment: Nice shadows under the magazines:) Are they drawn or did you use CA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` can take up an extreme amount of memory when working with a large number of rows. I ended up creating a single image view that was one row larger than the entire view using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`, then offset that view up or down a row as necessary when the view was about to scroll offscreen. Since the view is only moved at row boundaries, the performance was much better than I expected.

However, a better option would be to create a pool of individual `UImageViews` using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` and tile them, similar to what `UITableView` does will table view cells.

Apple has sample code which illustrates this technique in the ScrollView Suite sample project and the Designing Apps with Scroll Views video from WWDC 2010.

Answer (score 3):

I also needed to set UIView background from image and change its size at the same time. What I did was:

1. Created image within frame of my view size
2. Set view background using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage*)]`

And here is the code :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.followView.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_content.png"] drawInRect:self.followView.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

[followView setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a stretchable image of one shelf and then set it as the background for every cell on the tableview?

EDIT:

My knowledge of `AQGridView` is limited but sounds like you could get access to each individual 'grid tile'.

Try having three images per row:
- The image for the left most grid tile to show the left corner of your shelf
- The image for the center part of the shelf that is applied to all tiles except for the first and the last tile
- The image for the right most grid tile to show the right corner of your shelf.

Also, you should probably mention you're using `AQGridView` in your question so that other users won't think you're using a `UITableView`.

Comment: because i'm using grid cells [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) and not rows... :(